# Верси PHP, сбой скриптов, взлом сайта

Tags: php, wordpress

Всем привет! У меня есть сломанная версия сайта и при смене PHP версии начался постепенно рушится сайт, но возможно это просто совпадение, т.к. в этот день начала происходить спонтанно высокая нагрузка на сервер (ещё до того, как я начал менять версию PHP), но по началу была просто нагрузка, а спустя часов 10 сайт начал постепенно выходить из строя, плагин за плагином, при этом в одном из плагинов, а именно «WP Security»
сбросились все настройки защиты, похоже ли это на взлом или просто сломались скрипты? Кстати восстановив старую рез. копию, где не было нагрузок и прочего,
тоже появились спонтанные нагрузки, похоже ли это на DDoS?

Использую shared хостинг
Лимит оперативной памяти — 512 MB

Comment: в суппорт хостинга не пробовали обратииься? мб не у вас и проблема

Comment: Слишком широкий вопрос. SO не предназначен для длинных рассуждений. Лучше всего вам нанять специалиста, который восстановит сайт и ответит на 100 вопросов, которые у вас сейчас возникли.